# How to login into dropbox from my app

Tags: android, dropbox

I just want to login into Dropbox from my app. User will just enter username and password in
my edittexts and, after the user has pressed the login button of my application, the username and password should be matched with dropbox and a user token should be returned. 
Help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Dropbox API at:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#android

First, you need to create an app on https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps
Then, I will suggest that you read the documentation in the previous link... But it's not your edittexts that should handle the passwords and username, they will be forwarded to a where they authorize your app - and then youll recieve the token in `authenticationSuccessful()` callback

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing. Just download Dropbox API from https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android. There you can find an example program DBRoulette then you add these class to your program. It surely works.